# Magento 2 CE: Implement User Defined Quantity per Selection for Bundle Option of Select Type Checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textfield, magento2

### Description

**Magento 2** (Community Edition) standard for selection type checkbox of bundle options is that customers can not change the quantity of the selections.

I'm trying to implement that customers can change the quantity of each selection within an option of selection type checkbox -- as you can see [here](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-bundle-product-type-tutorial/) for **Magento 1**.

I followed the tutorial above and was able to rewrite the back-end blocks and the front-end blocks and view files (step 1 and 2) of **Magento 2**. Now I'm stuck at modifying the Javascript part (step 3).

Actually the quantity input fields of the checkbox selections are implemented like in the tutorial above (see step 2).

If I change the quantity of a selection, the function `_onQtyFieldChanged(event)` of *Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle.js* is called.
Inside this function `field.data('option')` is called. This usually returns an instance of the option (e.g. for selection type radio), which is used later in the function.

My problem is, that the `field.data('option')` call for the checkbox quantity field returns `undefined`.

### Debugging

- Dumping the `field` Object to the browsers console and calling `field.data()` returns an empty Object.
- Other `field.data` Objects (e.g. of selection type radio) have the attributes `option`, `optionId` and `optionValueId`. You can find this by inspecting the Object of the specific ID in the `cache` Object in line 3686 of the `jquery.js`.
- If I change the value of a checkbox quantity field and search for a radio quantity `field.data` Object in the mentioned `cache` Object, it has the attributes `optionContainer` and `quantityField`.
- If I change the value of a radio quantity field and search for a checkbox quantity `field` Object in the mentioned `cache` Object, it doesn't contain a `data` Object.

### Question

Has anyone an idea where the `field.data` Object is constructed and filled with the above mentioned attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I am actually following the same tutorial :) 
 I am stuck in the Javascript file part too, but it's in the overriding the `_onQtyFieldChanged(event)`

In terms of your issue:

The `field.data('option')` returns `undefined` because the `field` option is pointed to a `select` statement in the original implementation but not in yours. If you `console.log(field.data('option')` when you change your Bundle Product to have `dropdown` option type, you will see that the `<option></option>` that was selected from the dropdown will be the one that will be returned in the `console.log(field.data('option')`.

So to make it work, I used various elements from the implementation mentioned in the tutorial `Listing 15` image. For the case were `field.data('option')` doesn't exist.

If you inspect the front-end you will realize that each checkbox and qty text field is its own `input`. So when qty-field changes the `field` variable holds an `input` instead of an `option`. So to be able to access the selected "option" (input in our case), I used the a similar implementation to the one mentioned in the tutorial...

Tutorial:

`parts = element.id.split('-');
 optionId = parts[2]; ...`

Something like:

`parts = field[0].id.split('-');
 optionId = parts[2]; ...`

Not sure if this helps at all?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You put me on the right track. But you are not completely right. The `field.data('option')` refers to the e.g. radio element that is checked.  Now, I get the specific checkbox element by its ID and I extract the `optionId`and the `optionValueId` from the `field[0]` -- like you suggested.

Comment: After I got the right `optionConfig` element and set its `qty`, I can call `.trigger('change')` on it. Just like it is done for e.g. radio elements in the `_onQtyFieldChanged(event)`function. You can get the quantity by calling `field.val()`.

Comment: If you create a new question, we can discuss your overriding issue.

Comment: @Densen oh yeah I was referring to the dropdown Bundle Options instead of the radio button one. In that case, like you said it is the selected option from the dropdown or the radio button! I am glad you figured it out. I actually have a question open regarding the overriding issue. [Magento 2: How to override module price-bundle.js](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118153/magento-2-how-to-override-core-js-module-price-bundle-js) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days of working on this here's my solution.

you must override `bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js` in "Magento_Bundle/view/adminhtml/web/js/components"

to do that create `requirejs-config.js` in "app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml"

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Bundle/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox': 'Vendor_Module/js/bundle-user-defined-checkbox'
    }
}
};
```

then create `bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js` in "app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/web/js"

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox'
       ], function (Checkbox) {
'use strict';

return Checkbox.extend({
    defaults: {
        listens: {
            inputType: 'onInputTypeChange'
        }
    },

    /**
     * Handler for "inputType" property
     *
     * @param {String} data
     */
    onInputTypeChange: function (data) {
        data === 'multi' ?
            this.clear()
                .visible(false) :
            this.visible(true);
    }
});
});
```

clear cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and a checkbox will be added to the admin panel